# what's wrong with this include statement that i did in php?

Tags: php, html, include, syntax-error, parse-error

```
<?php

    include("articles/article_6.html");
?>
```

***i wanted the article to be posted on my website but it gives the error:***

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/white_coats/articles/article_6.html on line 1

Comment: How should we know?  We don't know what's in `article_6.html`.  The problem isn't with your include statement, other than that it appears that you're trying to include HTML and not PHP.  But, that shouldn't matter so much unless you have PHP tags in that file.

Comment: When you do `include` PHP basically just copies and pastes the contents of that file into the script.  The problem is inside the `article_6.html` file, like the error shows you.

Comment: article_6.html has no php tags. its just a word file that was saved in .html so that it could be displayed on the website. it's just an article with some pictures.

Comment: @AanchalAdhikari: Then `include` is the wrong tool to use here.  If you want to display the contents of the file, I'd use `echo file_get_contents("articles/article_6.html");`.  That way PHP just echos it out and doesn't try to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> article_6.html has no php tags. its just a word file that was saved in .html so that it could be displayed on the website. it's just an article with some pictures.

Then you don't *include* it. You *read* it's contents and print em. Include statements are nearly always for code includes and not plain html or text content.

```
echo file_get_contents("articles/article_6.html");
```